# Debugging Subroutines for Variable Defintions

Tags: debugging, fortran, subroutine

I have the two subroutines given below:

```
SUBROUTINE DENSITYMATRIXNEW(X,C,A,B,RHONEW)
IMPLICIT NONE
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1),INTENT(IN)::X
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS) :: RHO
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS), INTENT(OUT) :: RHONEW
REAL(KIND = DBL) :: ENERGYGAP, DELTA
REAL(KIND = DBL) :: ALPHA = SQRT(ENERGYGAP**2.0D0 + DELTA**2.0D0)
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2), INTENT(IN) :: A, B
REAL(KIND=DBL), DIMENSION(2,2), INTENT(IN) :: C
REAL(KIND=DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: TEMP1
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: TEMP2
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2) :: UNITARY, UNITARTCONJ
REAL(KIND = DBL) :: T
TEMP1 = COS((ALPHA*T)/2) * C
TEMP2 = ((ENERGYGAP/ALPHA)*A + (DELTA/ALPHA)*B)*SIN((ALPHA*T)/2)
UNITARY = TEMP1 - IMU * TEMP2
UNITARTCONJ = TEMP1 + IMU * TEMP2
CALL DENSITYMATRIX(X,RHO)
RHONEW = UNITARTCONJ*RHO*UNITARY
END SUBROUTINE DENSITYMATRIXNEW

SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION(X,C,A,B,D,ANS)
IMPLICIT NONE
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(DIMMAT,1),INTENT(IN) :: X
REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2),INTENT(IN) :: C
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(2,2), INTENT(IN) :: A, B
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMSYS,DIMSYS),INTENT(IN)::D
REAL(KIND = DBL), INTENT(OUT) :: ANS
COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMSYS, DIMSYS):: RHONEW
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(DIMSYS, DIMSYS) :: TEMP
INTEGER :: J
REAL(KIND = DBL)::SUMM
SUMM = 0.0D0
!CALL DENSITYMATRIX(X,RHO)
CALL DENSITYMATRIXNEW(X,C,A,B,D,RHONEW)
TEMP = MATMUL(D,RHONEW)
DO J = 1, DIMSYS
SUMM = SUMM + DREAL(TEMP(J,J))
END DO
ANS = SUMM
END SUBROUTINE EXPECTATION
```

When I run them as part of a larger program, I get the errors:

[image]

What could be the issue? I think I have defined all variables. I can't seem to debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors here so I'll try to explain each of the main ones

1. `REAL(KIND = DBL) :: ALPHA=SQRT(ENERGYGAP**2.0d0 + DELTA**2.0d0)` -- the error says `energygap has not been declared or is a variable , which does not reduce to a constant expression`. You're correct that you have declared `energygap` (and `delta`) in `densitymatrixnew` but you haven't give them a value so the compiler doesn't know what value to set `alpha` to. Essentially if you want to initialise a variable in the declaration `real :: a = b` then you need to make sure that the compiler knows what the value of `b` is at compile time. It's actually even stricter than this and `b` has to be declared as a parameter, I've given an example at the bottom of the list.
2. A `Type mismatch` in the call of `densitymatrixnew`. This one is quite easy, you've declared `densitymatrixnew` to take 5 arguments but when you call it you pass 6 arguments (note the extra `D` argument in the call).
3. `Can't open module file ...` you need to make sure you've compiled the file that contains the module `function_container` before you try to compile `SBWOcohNew.f` and ensure that the module file (*.mod) is available (easiest to just put it in this directory).

I hope that helps. In the future I'd recommend that you copy and paste the errors as text rather than providing a screenshot -- it makes everything much easier.

Example for point 1. The following would be allowed

```
subroutine test
   implicit none
   real, parameter :: b = 2.0
   real :: a = b
end subroutine
```

but the following would not

```
subroutine test
   implicit none
   real :: b = 2.0
   real :: a = b
end subroutine
```

Comment: Can I ask a question regarding point 1? Is it possible to initialize a local variable in the declaration line with another local variable (rather than with a named constant)? I tried it with gfortran but no success (with the above error message). Also, since the initialization implies the SAVE attribute automatically, I guess it would be safer to assign values after all the declaration of local variables are done.

Comment: @roygvib Yes it's definitely better to initialise after the declaration unless you really do want to add the save attribute (but then I'd personally explicitly add this anyway). I think `energygap` etc. would have to be declared as parameters for this to work (I'll edit to make this clearer).

Comment: Thanks, I feel the error message of gfortran above is a bit confusing... (if any "variable" is not allowed for use in initialization)